# jquery remove specific children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code  :

```
$('.TopNotificationIcon span').remove();
```

Can I replace `.TopNotificationIcon` with ***`this`*** i.e only `span` exists inside this specific class.

This is the structure

```
<div class="TopNotificationIcon"><span>xxxxx</span></div>
```

On click of `.TopNotificationIcon`, `span` should be removed.

Comment: not sure to understand exactly what you want? Do you want to test if a span is under a certain class or remove all span under TopNotification in a function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you have click event for `.TopNotificationIcon` you can do something like this

```
$('.TopNotificationIcon').click(function(){
    $('span',this).remove();    
});
```

Comment: my error was different but community claims this to be correct. so thanks for the tip hoping it's correct no time to check it out

Answer (score 15):

I would use the find() method, as it seems to be the fastest:

```
$("div.TopNotificationIcon").click(function() {

    $(this).find("span").remove();    

});
```

Comment: The context used by @TheSuperTramp is just a shorthand to `find()`.

Comment: Yes, but that just turns around and does a `find()`, does it not?  So, wouldn't it be more prudent to just use `find()` directly?

Comment: The difference is so minimal that you should use the one that is more readable and logical to you :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa - The gurus that I listen to always say that find() > context.  I know what you are saying, but what is minimal in the simplest form, could be larger in a complex form.  So removing an extra operation could be noticeable.

Comment: That's the kind of micro-optimization my gurus keep me away from.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all span under TopNotification you can do this :

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
    $(this).children('span').remove();    
});
```

It will remove all children in a div.

Comment: This is unnecessarily verbose. `$('.TopNotificationIcon span').remove();` is quite enough.

Answer (score 3):

Yes but youd need to change the line to:

```
$(this).children('span').remove();
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNhhh/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$('span').remove('.TopNotificationIcon');
```

This will remove all span elements with the class TopNotificationIcon and also child elements

Comment: This is not what the OP wanted. `.TopNotificationIcon` is one of the parents of the `span` to be removed.